# Add double click event on child node in angular-tree-widget

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular-tree-widget.js. We need to implement double click event once we click on any tree child node. All I found only two events are supported.

```
$scope.$on('selection-changed', function (e, node) {
    //node - selected node in tree
    $scope.selectedNode = node;
});
$scope.$on('expanded-state-changed', function (e, node) {
    // node - the node on which the expanded state changed
    // to see the current state check the expanded property
    //console.log(node.expanded);
    $scope.exapndedNode = node;    
});
```

How do I add double click event on a node here? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try this ng-dblclick=""...

Comment: How to add this property to node? We are building the tree in angular.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`ng-dblclick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDblclick), as @Manikandan suggested, in the following way:

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="TreeController" ng-dblclick="dblclick($event)">
    <tree nodes='treeFamily'></tree>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
controller('TreeController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.dblclick = function(evt) {
      angular.element(evt.target).toggleClass('red')
    }
    ...
}])
```

**Live Demo**

https://plnkr.co/edit/nWfiDA82WDpgRGnLqJUs?p=preview

As you can see, the idea is to subscribe to event on parent element of the tree and distinguish between tree items using `evt.target`, which is passed to event handler using angular's [`$event`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my question was "double click on child nodes of the tree". Which we are generating from database. if I double click on any of that node Is there a way I can handle the event?

Comment: @SushilGupta My code actually handles double click on any of child nodes of the tree, not only tree itself. Just check out the live demo